# Rabin-Karp string matching algorithm by rolling hash

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, hash, rabin-karp

Here is an implementation of Rabin-Karp String matching algorithm in C#...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  string A = "String that contains a pattern.";
  string B = "pattern";
  ulong siga = 0;
  ulong sigb = 0;
  ulong Q = 100007;
  ulong D = 256;
for (int i = 0; i < B.Length; i++)
{
    siga = (siga * D + (ulong)A[i]) % Q;
    sigb = (sigb * D + (ulong)B[i]) % Q;
}
if (siga == sigb)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(">>{0}<<{1}", A.Substring(0, B.Length), A.Substring(B.Length)));
    return;
}
ulong pow = 1;
for (int k = 1; k <= B.Length - 1; k++)
    pow = (pow * D) % Q;

for (int j = 1; j <= A.Length - B.Length; j++)
{
    siga = (siga + Q - pow * (ulong)A[j - 1] %Q) % Q;
    siga = (siga * D + (ulong)A[j + B.Length - 1]) % Q;
    if (siga == sigb)
    {
        if (A.Substring(j, B.Length) == B)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}>>{1}<<{2}", A.Substring(0, j), 
                                                             A.Substring(j, B.Length), 
                                                             A.Substring(j +B.Length)));
            return;
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Not copied!");
```

}

but it has one problem if i change the position of second string than it shows result not copied but

```
 string A = "String that contains a pattern.";
 string B = "pattern";
```

here it shows not copied

```
 string A = "String that contains a pattern.";
 string B = "Matches contains a pattern ";
```

i want to check whether it is copy from first string or not even i  would add something in it it or change the position but it shouldn't make difference so how to change it that it would  just compare the hashes of each word in string than implement it............

Comment: Related post - [Rabin Karp string matching algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10338379/465053)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
string B = "Matches contains a pattern ";
```

to

```
string B = "contains a pattern ";
```

and it will work

Comment: but that is not a solution what if i use two input file and want check them and second file is being edited by changing its position each and everything is there but it is copied so how would we check this?????????????

Comment: in this case what you have is not enough. check the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm#Rabin.E2.80.93Karp_and_multiple_pattern_search