# What is the best hash function for Rabin-Karp algorithm?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, pseudocode, rabin-karp

I'm looking for an efficient hash function for Rabin-Karp algorithm. Here is my actual code (C programming language).

```
static bool f2(char const *const s1, size_t const n1, 
               char const *const s2, size_t const n2)
{
    uintmax_t hsub = hash(s2, n2);
    uintmax_t hs   = hash(s1, n1);
    size_t   nmax = n2 - n1;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < nmax; ++i) {
        if (hs == hsub) {
            if (strncmp(&s1[i], s2, i + n2 - 1) == 0)
                return true;
        }
        hs = hash(&s1[i + 1], i + n2);
    }
    return false;
}
```

I considered some Rabin-Karp C implementations, but there are differences between all the codes. So my question is: what are the characteristics that a Rabin-Karp hash function should have?

Comment: Have you already seen [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm#Hash_function_used)?

Comment: Rabin-Karp cannot use just any hash function, it requires a specialised hash function that can be quickly calculated for a position i from the already known value for position (i-1).

Comment: Yes, @Gigi, I have. But if there were a bit better hash function, it would be perfect (because I will run this function many times). @rossum : According to the Wikipedia article, I did a `rehash' function.

Comment: Have you read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10339017/986743)?

Comment: @md5, maybe md5, anyway just joke :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A extremly good performing hash is the bernstein hash. It even outruns
many popular hashing algorithms.

```
unsigned bernstein_hash ( void *key, int len )
{
    unsigned char *p = key;
    unsigned h = 0;
    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < len; i++ )
        h = 33 * h + p[i];

    return h;
}
```

Of course, you can try out other hashing algorithms, as described here:
[Hash function on NIST](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/hash.html)

Note: It has never been explained why the `33` is performing so much better
than any other "more logic" constant.

For your interest: Here is a good comparison of different hash algorithms:
[strchr comparison of hash algorithms](http://www.strchr.com/hash_functions)

Comment: Is it OK that "unsigned" is overflowed in the arithmetic operation?

Comment: @Pupsik Overflows are in general not an issue, so I'd say yes.

Comment: How come this is accepted and a highly voted answer? It's time complexity is O(p). If this gets called for every window of the main text, the pattern search function will have time complexity O(p*t) which is same as the brute force approach. The question is about a hash function that works well with Rabin Karp algorithm. This function doesn't.

Comment: But Rabin-Carp's algorithm implies using of rolling hash function. Rolling hash function, is the function which have special properties:

if we already know value of H(c[0..n]), for example, we can compute H(c[1..n+1]) *quickly*. This is property of rolling hash function, which bernstein hash doesn't have!

I think, we should downvote this answer!

Comment: I'm not sure why comments claim this hash function can't be efficiently rolled. It's equivalent (modulo `sizeof(unsigned)`) to the pseudo-representation of a string in base 33. If your window has length `k`, you can "remove" `str[i - k]` from the hash by subtracting the hash by `pow(33, k - 1) * str[i-k]`. i.e. to roll the hash by one, you do `hash = 33 * (hash - pow(33, k -1) * str[i-k]) + str[i]`.

Answer (score 2):

> what are the characteristics that a Rabin-Karp hash function should have?

Rabin-Karp needs a [rolling hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash). The easiest rolling hash is a moving sum. Adler-32 and Buzhash are pretty simple too and perform better than a moving sum.

Any of these rolling hash techniques should work for Rabin-Karp:

- Moving sum

  - remove the oldest byte with subtraction
  - add a new byte with addition
- Polynomial rolling hash

  - remove the oldest byte with subtraction
  - add a new byte with multiplication and addition
- [Rabin fingerprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin_fingerprint)

  - a polynomial rolling hash whose polynomial is irreducible over [GF(2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_field)
- [Tabulation hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabulation_hashing)

  - remove the oldest byte with a table lookup and an `xor`
  - add a new byte with a table lookup and an `xor`
- [Cyclic polynomial](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/courses/graduate/676/recursivehashingp291-cohen), aka Buzhash

  - tabulation hashing based on circular shifts
- [Adler-32 checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adler-32)

  - not a rolling checksum by default but easily adjusted to "roll"
  - remove the oldest byte with two subtractions
  - add a new byte with two additions

Answer (score 0):

For the problem with the small alphabets, such as nucleic acid sequence searching (e.g. `alphabet = {A, T, C, G, U}`), [nt-Hash](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/32/22/3492/2525588) may be a good hash function.
It uses the binary operation, which is faster, and rolling hash update, and it also gives uniform distributed hash values.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the implementors of Java's JDK would have given some thought, I looked up what function is used there.

As of ~ Java 19, https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-19+23/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#L2326

The update function is:

```
h' = 31 * h + c
```

initial value is 0.